# .NET Publisher Policy Target Framework

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, semantic-versioning, publisher-policy

## SUMMARY

How do I create a publisher policy assembly that targets the same framework version as the redirected assembly?

## TL;DR

I have an `Assembly.dll` with version `1.x.y.0` and I also have a publisher policy for it named `policy.1.0.Assembly.dll` which redirects versions `1.0.0.0-1.x.y.0` to `1.x.y.0`.

The `Assembly.dll` targets .NET Framework 3.5. Am I right in thinking that the `policy.1.0.Assembly.dll` should also target .NET Framework 3.5 for things to work correctly on all frameworks 3.5+? If yes, how do I go about creating such a publisher policy assembly? I cannot see any relevant command line switch on the Assembly Linker (`AL`).

Currently when I GAC the assemblies, `Assembly.dll` ends up in `\Windows\assembly` and `policy.1.0.Assembly.dll` ends up in `\Windows\Framework.NET\assembly`. ILDASM shows me that the targeted runtimes are different:

**`Assembly.dll`**:

```
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern System
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
```

**`policy.1.0.Assembly.dll`**:

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .hash = (B6 24 5D 64 2D 23 95 0B 50 19 B4 DC 19 4B 9A E8   // .$]d-#..P....K..
           B9 FF C0 53 )                                     // ...S
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Assembly Linker from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin` appears to produce a `policy.1.0.Assembly.dll` that targets the correct runtime:

```
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .hash = (15 3B C0 4F 38 2D 09 20 CC A2 58 01 EE B1 AB E2   // .;.O8-. ..X.....
           D2 D0 C5 11 ) 
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
```

While this appears to do what I want, it is unclear whether:

- It is actually necessary.
- How long will the older `AL.EXE` be shipped with Visual Studio.

---

Lucian's VBlog was helpful in letting me understand how SDK tools are organized:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2008/11/14/where-are-the-sdk-tools-where-is-ildasm/